# Swift allows declaring variable name the same with parameter name or function name

Tags: swift

I'm new to Swift and I don't quite understand how Xcode won't throw errors with the code below

```
func foo(param: Int)->Int{
  let param: Int = 5
  return param
}
var foo: Int = 5
print(foo)
```

As you can see, Swift allows me to declare variable `param` with the same name with function parameter. Also I'm allowed to declare a variable with the same name as the function name.
Can anyone help me explain this. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

1. `foo` and `foo(param:` are different signatures.

   However this is not allowed

   ```
   let foo = foo(param: 12)
   ```

   You get the error

   > Variable used within its own initial value
2. Parameter labels and local variables are in different name spaces. A local variable hides the parameter label.

   It's even possible to declare a member `param` in a struct. To address the struct member you have to add `self`

   ```
   struct Foo {

       var param = 0

       mutating func foo(param: Int) -> Int {
           let param = 10 + param // 15
           self.param = param * 20 // 300
           return param // 15
       }
   }

   var f = Foo()
   print(f.foo(param: 5)) // 15
   print(f.param) // 300
   ```

Comment: For the record, hiding a parameter label with a local variable is called "variable shadowing".

Answer (score 0):

Function and Instance Variables are two different entity in this case. Swift will not allow function and variable name with same when there is no parameter in function.